# MockBean not injected in MVC Controller test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test my controller in isolation of the spring application context.

Here is my Controller

```
@RestController
public class AddressesController {

    @Autowired
    service service;

    @GetMapping("/addresses/{id}")
    public Address getAddress( @PathVariable Integer id ) {
        return service.getAddressById(id);
    }
}
```

My service interface

```
public interface service {
    Address getAddressById(Integer id);
}
```

And here is my test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class AddressControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    service myService;

    @Test
    public void getAddressTest() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doReturn(new Address()).when(myService).getAddressById(1);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/addresses/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Here is the exception I'm getting:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException:  Argument
>   passed to when() is null! Example of correct stubbing:
>       doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod(); Also, if you use @Mock annotation don't miss initMocks()

It is like the service is never created. How could I solve this problem?

We can solve this problem by using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` in place of `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. Could someone explaines why it deed work? Normally the first annotation is for junit4 and the later for junit5.

Comment: `@MockBean` is not Mockito annotation. Try `@Mock` instead

Comment: nothing change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the problem was solved because of dependencies problem.

My pom.xml file contains the `spring-boot-starter-test`, if we check what contains this starter, we will find that it contains junit4 as dependency and not junit5.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

As I'm trying to use Junit5 in my test classes with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), the test unfortunatly compile but gives a runtime error.
I solved that by excluding the junit4 from the spring boot starter:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

My pom.xml should also contains junit5 dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```